# How to animate the color of a text with multiple colors flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, text, widget

I want my text  to animate through  multiple colors  in flutter how can I do it.

Comment: there are few different type of animation in flutter... watch this youtube series about animation from the flutter team https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjxrf2q8roU2v6UqYlt_KPaXlnjbYySua

Comment: and they have an episode about changing color.

Comment: thanks man let me check that out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pablo's answer (using ColorTween) will animate the color between two values. In order to transition among several colors, you can  adapt that solution to either

- build a "TweenSequence" chaining multiple color tweens
- use [RainbowColor](https://pub.dev/packages/rainbow_color) which simplifies transition between multiple colors

See my article [Multicolor Transitions in Flutter](https://medium.com/@ilikerobots/multicolor-animations-in-flutter-1ab036ba2286) for a walkthrough on doing either.

For reference, here's a multi-color (B->G->R) animated text widget using RainbowColor.

```
class ColorText extends StatefulWidget {
  const ColorText({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ColorTextState createState() => _ColorTextState();
}

class _ColorTextState extends State<ColorText>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation<Color> _colorAnim;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 3), vsync: this);
    _colorAnim = RainbowColorTween([Colors.blue, 
                                    Colors.green, 
                                    Colors.red, 
                                    Colors.blue])
            .animate(controller)
              ..addListener(() { setState(() {}); })
              ..addStatusListener((status) {
                if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
                  controller.reset();
                  controller.forward();
                } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
                  controller.forward();
                }
              });
    controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Hello!", style: TextStyle(color: _colorAnim.value));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The example below animate a text color through a Colors range.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation animation;
  Color color;

  @override
  @mustCallSuper
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller=AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 5)
    );
    animation=ColorTween(begin:Colors.red,end: Colors.white).animate(controller);

    animation.addListener((){
      setState(() {
        color=animation.value;
      });
    });

    controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(home:Scaffold(

        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Example")),
        body:Center(child:Text("HELLO!!!",textScaleFactor:3,style: TextStyle(color: color),))));
  }
}
```